# html multidimensional array to php multidimensional array - array overwritten

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```html
<div id="pkg1-items">
  <div class="col-md-2 ">
    <label>Item 1 :</label>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 ">
    <div class="input-control select " data-role="input">
      <input name="item[0][name]" type="text " placeholder="Enter Item " required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 ">
    <label>Option 1 :</label>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 ">
    <div class="input-control select " data-role="input">
      <input name="item[0][option1]" type="text " placeholder="Enter Option To Item" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 ">
    <label>Option 2 :</label>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 ">
    <div class="input-control select " data-role="input">
      <input name="item[0][option2]" type="text " placeholder="Enter Option To Item  " required>

    </div>
  </div>
```

script which dynamically adds input

```
$(document).on('click', 'label[id^="pkg"]', function() {
            var pkg = this.id;
            var clickeditem  = '#'+this.id +'-items';
            i++;
            $('<div class="clearfix"></div><div class="col-md-2 "> <label>Item  : </label></div><div class="col-md-2 "> <div class="input-control select " data-role="input"> <input name="item['+i+']['+'name'+']" type="text " placeholder="Enter Item " required> </div></div><div class="col-md-2 "> <label>Option 1 : </label></div><div class="col-md-2 "> <div class="input-control select " data-role="input"> <input name="item['+i+']['+'option1'+']" type="text " placeholder="Enter Option To Item" required> </div></div><div class="col-md-2 "> <label>Option 2 : </label></div><div class="col-md-2 "> <div class="input-control select " data-role="input"> <input name="item['+i+']['+'option2'+']" type="text " placeholder="Enter Option To Item " required> </div></div>').appendTo(clickeditem); 


            return false;
    });
```

send.php

```
$i=0;
        //$string = "";
        $items = array( array() ); 
        $item = $_POST['item'];
        $icnt = count($items); 
        $pkg = $_POST['Packages'];
        $nop = count($_POST['Packages']);

        for ( $i = 0 ; $i< $icnt ; $i ++ ) {
            $items[$i][0] = $item[$i]['name'];
            $items[$i][1] = $item[$i]['option1'];
            $items[$i][2] = $item[$i]['option2'];



        } 
    echo '<br/><hr/>';
            print_r($items);
            echo '<br/><hr/>';
    }
```

The above gives output - 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => item1[1] => option1[2] => option2) )

given that the inputs were - item1 , option1 , option2 . Although three or more inputs were added but the array gets overwritten and outputs the last value only . how can I use a dynamic multidimensional array in php . If I define the array with specific row and cols the above will work fine .

Comment: where is declared?? globally?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)`, check what really is being received. and how are you submitting the form? normal form click-to-submit, or an ajax call?

Comment: What is the value of 'i' in: input name="dpkg['+i+']['+'item'+']" You're not setting 'i' to any value so do they all have the same name?

Comment: @MarcB I am using simple form ..

Comment: The value of i changes when another function is trigger which increases the value of i ad makes it dpkg[1] , dpkg[2] and so on .... @GreggDuncan

Answer (score 0):

```
$items[$i][] = $item[$i]['name'];
        $items[$i][] = $item[$i]['option1'];
        $items[$i][] = $item[$i]['option2'];
```

removed the index from the $items[$i][0] to $items[$i][]

Problem solved.